# Refresh user data when value in dropdown is changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, templates, pug

I am using Mongodb, Express, NodeJS, Pug template for my application.

I am querying for all users and passing it to the template. From the front-end, when I hit the route I want to display username for all the users in a dropdown. When we select a username from the dropdown I want to display all related data to that user. When we select different usernames the data refreshes.

I am just confused on how to implement this in pug templates.

Help appreciated!

```
extends base
block content
    select.form-control#exampleFormControlSelect1
        each user in users
            option= user.name
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @sean added little bit code I have so far